# cmake: Include directories root?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to set up cmake for a project I'm working on, but I have a problem which I can't resolve currently. My project has the following folder structure:

```
MotorEngine (root dir)
| CMakeLists.txt
| ThirdParty
|-| SDL2
|-|-| include (contains all header files for SDL2)
|-|-| lib
|-|-|-| x64
|-|-|-|-| SDL2.lib (the library file I need to link with)
| Source
|-| CMakeLists.txt
|-| main.cpp
```

The root CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(MotorEngine)

# Set an output directory for our binaries
set(BIN_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Binaries)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Binaries)
set(THIRDPARTY_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty)

# Include SDL2
include_directories(${THIRDPARTY_PATH}/SDL2/include)

# Add the engine + third party subdirectory
add_subdirectory(Source)
```

The Source's CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(MotorEngine)
add_executable(MotorEngine main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MotorEngine ${THIRDPARTY_PATH}/SDL2/lib/x64/SDL2.lib)
```

Now, I want to achieve the following, in the main.cpp I want to write

```
#include "SDL2/include/SDL2.h"
```

But currently I have to write

```
#include "SDL2.h"
```

Since there will be files with the same name later on, I need to distinguish them in their folders. So the easiest would be to add the "ThirdParty" folder as a root so I can use #include relative to that then, but doing

```
include_directories(${THIRDPARTY_PATH})
```

does not work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You may try to change `include_directories` to `target_include_directories` and specify `MotorEngine` as target explicitly.

Comment: @k.v. I'm a total noob when it comes to cmake terms, how would I do that?

Comment: `target_include_directories(MotorEngine, ${THIRDPARTY_PATH})` @iRedCraft

Comment: I looked the command up since I had some errors, modified it and now it works! I'll write an answer to my own question here.

Comment: You should create an imported library target and set the [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) to it.

Comment: @MizuxDev I'd like to do that, but it still doesn't include them, if I do the following: https://pastebin.com/mva5zYy8 (CMakeLists.txt inside the SDL folder)

Comment: @iRedCraft It should work ! Did you `add_subdirectory(ThirdParty/SDL2)` in your root CMakeLists.txt before `add_subdirectory(Source)`, then in `Source/CMakeLists.txt` a `target_link_libraries(MotorEngine PUBLIC SDL2)` should work to have the include path (you can use `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)` to check). After if you want `"SDL2/include/SDL2.h"` you should create your imported target in ThirdParty/CMakeLists.txt and not in ThirdParty/SDL2 ...

After usually include are `foo.h` or `foo/foo.h` not `foo/include/foo.h` IMHO

Comment: @MizuxDev I have now the following setup: https://pastebin.com/gCJ2BLvC but still I can't include "SDL.h" nor "SDL2/SDL.h" nor "SDL2/include/SDL.h" :/

Comment: in your pastebin your root CMakeLists.txt should contains `add_subdirectory(${THIRDPARTY_PATH})` and not `add_subdirectory(${THIRDPARTY_PATH}/SDL2)` (need to remove the SDL2)

Comment: @MizuxDev Tried it, but it isn't added to the project's include paths, therefore I still can't include it

Answer (score 1):

With help of [k.v.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2466572/k-v) I was able to sort this out. I needed to add the following in the CMakeLists.txt in the Source directory:

```
target_include_directories(MotorEngine PUBLIC ${THIRDPARTY_PATH})
```